# widget remove itself

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

i have widget like below

### in ui.xml

```
 textbox, anchor_delete
```

when anchor_delete is press, @uihandler fired and i want entire widget textbox and anchor_delete remove itself from the view.  Is this possible

```
@UiHandler("anchor_delete")
void deleteRowAction(ClickEvent event) {

   getWidget().removeFromParent(); //i tried this but fail
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
textbox.removeFromParent();
anchor_delete.removeFromParent();
```

Assuming both are widgets.